# flexbox align center vertical and horizontal not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, flexbox

I know the basic concepts behind to center a flex container, using justify content:center and align-items center, the thing is that the box is not aligned properly :S

**This is what i tried so far:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <main class="container">
        <div class="container__left">
          <div>I'm Jonathan Doe</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum v Lorem ipsumv Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum v v</div>
          <ul>
            <li>one bla bla bla</li>
            <li>two bla bla bla</li>
            <li>three bla bla bla</li>
          </ul>
          <div>
            <button>first</button>
            <button>second</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container__right">

        </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App"
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo");

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: "Exo", sans-serif;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80%;
  border: 8px solid #3f3f3f;
}

.container__left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 48% 100%, 0 100%);
  background-color: #1c1f24;
}
</style>
```

something wrong with the width and height maybe, but i can't figure out what is wrong with that, any help?

Comment: you have no element with class `.main`. only a `main` element. so flex is not applied

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that, u were using **.main** instead of **main** in ur css.
Second thing is that, u dont need flexbox for centering ur box,

```
margin:auto;
```

on container is enough

Check the snippet below

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: "Exo", sans-serif;
}

.main-parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

main {
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80%;
  border: 8px solid #3f3f3f;
}

.container__left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 48% 100%, 0 100%);
  background-color: #1c1f24;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-parent">
  <main class="container">
    <div class="container__left">
      <div>I'm Jonathan Doe</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum v Lorem ipsumv Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum v v</div>
      <ul>
        <li>one bla bla bla</li>
        <li>two bla bla bla</li>
        <li>three bla bla bla</li>
      </ul>
      <div>
        <button>first</button>
        <button>second</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container__right">

    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: on full page it is not centered the margin auto is not working properly

Comment: seems like it need flex :D